# Finding a value of a property in a JavaScript object inside an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, iterator

I have managed to pull some users back from my firebase database and am outputting them into the console

`[Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]`

Each object has:

```
gender: "male"
liked: "liked"
name: "ed"
not_liked: "liked"
username: "ed@ed.com"
useruid: "HSRcN6PuylXbv87kSWxKVtWffaI3"
```

how can I go through the array and say if the `useruid` with a value `HSRcN6PuylXbv87kSWxKVtWffaI3` then `console.log()` the associated name. In this case `ed`

my pseudo attempt :

```
if (Object.gender.includes('male')) {
    console.log('yes')
} 
else {
    console.log('nah')
}
```

Comment: Use a loop and an if-statement? Please show us what you tried.

Comment: updated code @Bergi

Comment: But where's the loop, what is `Object`? And why are you accessing `gender` when you say you're interested in the `useruid`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering you are storing array in `dataArray` variable in javascript.

```
for (i = 0; i < dataArray.length; i++) { 
    if(dataArray[i].useruid=="HSRcN6PuylXbv87kSWxKVtWffaI3"){
        console.log(dataArray[i].username);
    }
}
```

It will print `username` on console for `userid=HSRcN6PuylXbv87kSWxKVtWffaI3`

Comment: No problem. Let me know if there is any issue

Answer (score 0):

Simply loop through your array and throw a log when a match has been found.

```
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
     if(arr[i].useruid === "HSRcN6PuylXbv87kSWxKVtWffaI3") {
          console.log(arr[i].username);
     }
}
```

As for your pseudo attempt:

```
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
     if(arr[i].gender === "male") {
          console.log("User is male");
     }
     else {
          console.log("User is female");
     }
}
```